# how to set year in textbox to be 1970 above

Tags: php, validation

Please Help me with this code..I want my year textbox from 1970 year and above and must be number cannot be null

```
    if(is_numeric($_POST['DateOfBirth_Year'])){
    $DateOfBirth_Year = $_POST['DateOfBirth_Year'];
}
else if (is_numeric($_POST['DateOfBirth_Year'] < '1970')){
    echo '<p><font color = "red">Please enter the year above 1970!</font></p>';
}


else {

    echo '<p><font color="red">Enter NUMBER for the year of date of birth!</font></p>';
}
```

Comment: `$_POST['DateOfBirth_Year'] > 1970`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(is_numeric($_POST['DateOfBirth_Year']) && $_POST['DateOfBirth_Year'] > 1970) {
    // it's ok
} else {
    // not ok
}
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: I need help on how to add on that my month have certain day like february is 28 days

Comment: if ($_POST['DateOfBirth_Day'] == '1') {
    $DateOfBirth_Day = $_POST['DateOfBirth_Day'];// 1
} 
else if ($_POST['DateOfBirth_Day'] == '2') {
    $DateOfBirth_Day = $_POST['DateOfBirth_Day'];// 2
}
else if ($_POST['DateOfBirth_Day'] == '3') {
    $DateOfBirth_Day = $_POST['DateOfBirth_Day'];// 3
}
else if ($_POST['DateOfBirth_Day'] == '4') {
    $DateOfBirth_Day = $_POST['DateOfBirth_Day'];// 4
}

else {
 echo '<p><font color = "red">Please select - day - for Date of Birth!</font></p>';
    
}

Comment: Just add ` && $_POST['DateOfBirth_Day'] <= cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $_POST['DateOfBirth_Month'], $_POST['DateOfBirth_Year'])`

Comment: what do you mean? Add under which part? what is cal_gregorian?

Comment: Just add that before closing the if statement. CAL_GREGORIAN is a constant and it stands for the current in-use calendar. [cal_days_in_month](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.cal-days-in-month.php) returns the number of days in a specified month. And "&&" stands for "and" so you just need to add another condition ( and day <= number of days in the month ). You also need to add ` && day >= 1`. I forgot about it. So it shouldn't accept days like "-1".

Comment: if ($_POST['DateOfBirth_Day'] == '1' && $_POST['DateOfBirth_Day'] <= cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $_POST['DateOfBirth_Month'], $_POST['DateOfBirth_Year'])) {

Comment: if(is_numeric($_POST['DateOfBirth_Year']) && $_POST['DateOfBirth_Year'] > 1970 && $_POST['DateOfBirth_Day'] <= cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $_POST['DateOfBirth_Month'], $_POST['DateOfBirth_Year']) && $_POST['DateOfBirth_Day'] >= 1) { ...

Answer (score 0):

For better validation on year you'd better define a range of numbers that can be obtained as year:

```
$years = range(1970,2000); // for example
```

and check if posted year is in the array:

```
in_array($_POST['DateOfBirth_Year'], $years);
```

So your last code could be:

```
$years = range(1970,2000);
if (!in_array($_POST['DateOfBirth_Year'], $years))
{
    echo '<p><font color = "red">Please enter the year above 1970!</font></p>';
}
```

You don't need the other redundant codes.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( $_POST['DateOfBirth_Year'] < 1970 ){
  echo '<p><font color = "red">Please enter the year above 1970!</font></p>';

}else{
  echo '<p><font color="red">Enter NUMBER for the year of date of birth!</font></p>';
}
```

In your second if statement you have, `is_numeric($_POST['DateOfBirth_Year'] < '1970')` which is testing if the result of the comparison `$_POST['DateOfBirth_Year'] < '1970'` is numeric.  The test for [is_numeric](http://www.php.net/is_numeric) is unnecessary.

Why do you have the first `if` statement? You do not reference $DateOfBirth_Year in your code.

```
if(is_numeric($_POST['DateOfBirth_Year'])){
  $DateOfBirth_Year = $_POST['DateOfBirth_Year'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a solution,**

```
if(
  (is_numeric($_POST['DateOfBirth_Year']))&&
  ((int)($_POST['DateOfBirth_Year'])<1970)
 )
 {
     echo '<p><font color = "red">Please enter the year above 1970!</font></p>';
 }
 else {
      echo '<p><font color="red">Enter NUMBER for the year of date of birth!</font></p>';
     }
```